# Monitor clipboard activity cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is it possible to "watch" a users clipboard in cocoa?

For example if my app was a system tray style app like the dropbox client could i subscribe to events raised when a user hits copy / paste in another app?

Answer (score 1):

You could always check out Apple's sample code, [ClipboardViewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008825-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).  It does something sort of similar to what you're trying to do.

Comment: There's nothing in there about "watching" the clipboard though.