# Monitor clipboard in Mac OS

Tags: cocoa, macos, monitoring, clipboard

I need to monitor clipboard events in my mac os app. I found a sample for a [clipboard viewer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/ClipboardViewer/Introduction/Intro.html) and another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001400/monitor-clipboard-activity-cocoa) in stackoverflow asking for the same thing, but none of them has a solution on how to monitor the clipboard events.

That is, immediately after the user hits command + c, I get an event notifying.  I know that the functionality exists, as there is an [app](http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Utilities/Pasteboard-Recorder.shtml) that uses this functionality

Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I receive a callback whenever an NSPasteboard is written to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5033266/can-i-receive-a-callback-whenever-an-nspasteboard-is-written-to)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have written a clipboard listener [it will print every new text based information that entered the clipboard] in native Java see the following code:

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;  
import java.awt.datatransfer.*;  
import java.io.IOException;  

public class ClipboardListener extends Thread implements ClipboardOwner {

    Clipboard systemClipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();  

    public void run(){  
        Transferable selection = systemClipboard.getContents(this);  
        gainOwnership(selection);  
        while (true) {}
    }  

    public void gainOwnership(Transferable t){ 
        try {this.sleep(100);} 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        systemClipboard.setContents(t, this);  
    }  

    public void lostOwnership(Clipboard clipboard, Transferable contents) {
        try {System.out.println((String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));} 
        catch (UnsupportedFlavorException e) {} 
        catch (IOException e) {}
        gainOwnership(contents);  
    }  
}
```

---

```
public class myApp {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ClipboardListener listener = new ClipboardListener();
        listener.start();}
}
```

It works, but the application will need focus to get the event from the clipboard. [I'm not Mac OS X developer so I don't how to fix this, actually I have posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185754/handling-a-clipboard-on-mac-os-x-java) about it...]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingKeyEvents/HandlingKeyEvents.html).  You could watch for command + c (and x) and manually get the clipboard.

Comment: What happens if the user selects Copy from the Edit menu?

Comment: True… I'm not sure if there is a way to do that

Comment: Are you sure that the application you mentioned supports this? So it's able to monitor the selection of the NSMenu?

Comment: @larcus did you mean to comment on the question?

Comment: what? I don't understand what you mean.